# Facebook API - how to get scope pages_manage_metadata

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I created a messenger application for my clients. I need to get the scope "pages_manage_metadata" to be able to set webhook for their pages.

But test user can only get these scopes

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UG6r1.png

I cannot test my application on a test user and his page because the incoming messages are not working. I can not send an approval request and write how to use my application

Please tell me how to implement this function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test users don’t work well for stuff that is related to pages. They can not interact with any “real” pages, only pages created by the test user account itself.

Use a real user account, that you add to a role in your app (admin/developer/tester; note that “tester” and “test user” are two different things), and use that account for your testing during development. If you don’t want to interfere with any live pages that user might be an admin of, then create a new page for your testing purposes first.

Comment: I registered a new user and added him to my application as a tester. 
http://prntscr.com/v8lmrt I added a company for this user and verified him. 
I request two scopes - pages_manage_metadata and pages_messaging http://prntscr.com/v8lnad But this throws an error

"Some of the permissions below have not been approved for use by Facebook."
http://prntscr.com/v8lnkh Scope pages_manage_metadata not work (. If I add as a developer, then another error is displayed http://prntscr.com/v8lqub http://prntscr.com/v8lren

Comment: My APP always in live mode http://prntscr.com/v8lzhv. I read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions, but I don’t understand what’s wrong. PLS help me

Comment: Despite the documentation for dev/live mode saying otherwise, there are a few permission these days, that even users with a role in the app can not be asked for in live mode, if the permission was not approved in review yet. Put your app into dev mode (or create a _test app_ version of your existing app, if you can not take that out of live mode), and try then.

Comment: facebook documentation is not complete... I got full rights to scopes http://prntscr.com/v97ovh But now the key that facebook returns does not work... Request https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=[access_token] return Malformed access token 190. But earlier, access_token obtained in this way returned data

Comment: I'm confused about facebook

Comment: Something about your token must not be right then. Make sure it didn’t get truncated, and debug it via https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

Comment: After success auth facebook redirect me to URL that has access_token,  there can be no mistake. http://prntscr.com/v98omw The link you gave also reports an error http://prntscr.com/v98pyu. but before i had working access_token http://prntscr.com/v98sem why the key returned by facebook might not work?

Comment: You got a `code` parameter there, not an access token. That code needs to be _exchanged for_ an access token first of all now - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#confirm

Comment: thanks! I've been dealing with scopes for so long that I forgot about this

Comment: I walked a few steps forward and again at a dead end. My webhook is work http://prntscr.com/v9b5fd http://prntscr.com/v9b907 I setup subscribed_fields http://prntscr.com/v9b6op but when i write a message from the tester or admin (real user) on page assigned with app it has no effect in webhook script. I don’t understand something again?

Comment: Can’t tell you that, from the outside, you’ll have to do a bit of debugging then. I’d start by checking the web server access logs, to see if any requests from Facebook were made to your server - to first of all narrow down whether the problem is on your end, or something with the setup on the FB side of things.